# Building with libc++ and gcc: -Wmaybe-uninitalized

Tags: c++, g++, debian, libc++

I am running a build with gcc and libc++ (llvm). Since update to debian bookworm I get:

```
/usr/lib/llvm-14/include/c++/v1/regex:1384:8: warning: ‘<unnamed>.std::__1::__state<char>::__at_first_’ may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
```

(along with a lot of other logs)

I have dumbed the problem down to this example:

example.cpp:

```
#include <regex>

int doIt()
{
   std::regex r("bla");
   return 0;
}
```

compiler call:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -Wmaybe-uninitialized -O1 -nostdinc++ -isystem /usr/lib/llvm-14/include/c++/v1/ -c example.cpp
```

Needed apt packages: g++, libc++-14-dev

When I remove the optimization (`-O1`), then the issue is gone. If I use all the separate optimizations from [this list](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), the issue is gone. When i use the `std::regex` constructor with no args, the issue is gone.

Questions:

1. Am I doing something wrong with compiler settings?
2. Is this a bug? Is it a bug for gcc or libc++?
3. How can I fix this without adding `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmaybe-uninitialized"` to all includes of `<regex>`?

Comment: Maybe you shorten too much the example. In your case: r is not used, so compiler (with optimizer) will not initialize it, so the warning. You may argue that it could also remove the variable altogether, so it is a missed optimization, OTOH I assume it is not so frequent, and the warning helps (if I see it, I would assume a unfinished code, or some error on logic (maybe later I misspelled 's' instead of 'r')

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Good idea. Have you tried this? If i use it (https://pastebin.com/Lz44DJkb), the same warning appears. (doItRegex(r) uses it, right?)

Comment: I think it is better to test `std::cout << r.mark_count();` instead of `doItRegex(r);` because function calls can get optimized away.

Comment: @theSparky Same warning appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Using WSL2 Debian Bookworm, confirmed the same issue.

Seems to be a minor issue of `__at_first_` not being initialized in LLVM at

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/17fc78e7a4e178482650f2a1c18954823c5cd4eb/libcxx/include/regex#L1462

because

```
~$> sudo sed -i 's/          __node_(nullptr), __flags_() {}/          __node_(nullptr), __flags_(),__at_first_(false) {}/' /usr/lib/llvm-14/include/c++/v1/regex
```

allowed the build command you used to compile as expected:

```
~$> /usr/bin/g++ -Wmaybe-uninitialized -O1 -nostdinc++ -isystem /usr/lib/llvm-14/include/c++/v1/ -c example.cpp
~$>
```

However, for me, linking was only possible with:

```
~$> /usr/bin/g++ -Wmaybe-uninitialized -O1 example.cpp
~$> ./a.out
Text contains the phrase 'regular expressions'
Found 20 words
...
```

Comment: Regarding the your last paragraph. You are saying libc++ does not print but libstdc++ does? What is the code used here?

Comment: Since your original command specified the -c option, could you share more info on how you are wanting to link your object files?

Comment: I have put together a full executable and the commandline: https://pastebin.com/iQr3dDsw. It is printing to stdout and the same warning is appearing.